# How to Restore previous working code of Web App from github?

Tags: git, github, web, version-control, restore

I was adding some new Features into my web app, then i made a huge mistake by using wrong git commands, now i want to restore the previous version of my app, please provide me step by step guide .

i was trying to go back to previous version and made some mistake and restored wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to know where you want to go back. Log your history and note the reference of the commit you are interested in. If it's the last commit, just note `HEAD~1`.

```bash
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 8120633 (HEAD -> main, origin/main) The Mistake.
* 10b539f The last commit
* 872f82b An other commit
...
```

Reset your working directory on it.

```bash
$ git reset <commit>
```

Then push this work again with the meta-information of the said commit.

```bash
$ git commit -a -c <commit>
$ git push
```